# How to manually set an Angular template driven form as invalid in angular9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-template-form

I want to manually set the **EmployeeForm** as Invalid from the .ts file. Here **EmployeeForm** is a Template driven form.

I have tried to do the following but it didn't work.

```
this.EmployeeForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
```

error message says:

> **Property 'setErrors' does not exist on type 'NgForm'. Did you mean 'getError'**?

The same code works when I use it with other forms which are **Reactive forms**

Comment: Please add more information about EmployeeForm, your issue, and you tried to do

Comment: I have stated the issue and updated what I was trying and what error did I get.

Comment: Is it working with `incorrect` instead of `invalid` ?

Comment: no it's not working using `incorrect` . the error is in the method name `setErrors` .

Comment: Can you add the form template and the complete ts file?

Comment: Maybe the best way will be to set all your controls as invalid like this `this.EmployeeForm.controls.forEach(control => control.setErrors({'invalid':true}))` or `setErrors({'incorrect':true})` don't remember which one the good.

Comment: `This expression is not callable.
  Type 'AbstractControl' has no call signatures.` it didn't work @Alexis

Comment: `this.EmployeeForm.form.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });` worked finally. Thanks for the effort @Alexis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this worked

```
this.EmployeeForm.form.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the template reference to your control input.
Then, you can access the form control and add the errors which you want.

Ex:
`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel">`

Reference: [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages).